# How do I print a new line in specs html report

Tags: javascript, jasmine, mocha.js, chai

We have chai specs with describe() and it()s for our UI. I am trying to make our specs more business friendly since our business is used to cucumber GWTs I am trying to write GWT in It() block so that html report would print Given when and then for each spec/it()

I have tried the following:

```
it('Given something'+'<br />'+
        'When something<br />' +
        'Then something', function () {

    });

it('Given something\n'+'When something\n'+'Then something', function () {

    });
```

No matter what I do in it(), in the html report it does not print 3 different lines, it always prints like this:

[spec html report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLvL0.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `\n`. Like `'Given something \n When something'`, because this syntax works in jasmine and protractor.